# Create fillable PDF from PDF

Tags: forms, pdf, image-processing, automation

I'm trying to create an editable PDF from an existing PDF. There are Textbox fields, however, my PDF has got images similar to checkbox. The Acrobat Pro is not detecting those controls as checkboxes. There are around 200 checkboxes in my PDf which is tedious to replace them with checkbox controls manually. Is there a way to identify those images as checkboxes programmatically and create the controls automatically?

Comment: Think about this from a programming perspective.  How could you programmatically tell that an image was meant to be a checkbox...  That type of AI is not within the realm of what Adobe can do.

Comment: Programatically? via Optical Mark Recognition.

Answer (score 1):

If you use the **Premium** version of OmniForm you can convert to PDF, then do your final editing in Acrobat. Much easier than trying to build it using the Acrobat Pro 9 Form Wizard to create forms from paper or electronic documents.

Answer (score 0):

No, there isn't.

Answer (score 0):

Try Omniform from Scansoft/Nuance .. for some people it works better at detecting checkbox like structures on the image than Acrobat Pro 9.